# missing unstaged files in egit using eclipe form existing project

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I want to make a git repository for my mod i am trying to make. I created a github remote repository and now want to create a local repository to then push to github so that I can share it with some friends.

When i make the repository in eclipse using egit I right click on the project name>Team>share project. A new window pops-up i select git then mark the project which i want to git. I first tried to unmark the "Use or create repository in parent forlder of project" and made a repository  (later I also tried with this option).

Now behind the project name appears [test.test NO-HEAD]. and in my git staging view i have 3 unstaged changes : .classpath .gitnore and .project

Although I have already over 100 files in my project is still only shows 3 unstaged files. How do i make egit also stage the files i already had in my project?

Answer (score 0):

**You simply have to make your first commit**. Do Team>Commit and in the following dialog you will see all your files.

Comment: Commited and still not there but now after my project name it says test.test master

Comment: It actually shows the repository name and current branch. Are you sure you have those files in your git work area?